# How to swap fields of 2 objects in java?

Tags: java, object, reference, swap

I have two objects of class TreeNode. Those are called a and b with the following fields:

```
value
index
parent
leftChild 
rightChild
```

I want to create a function

```
swap(a,b)
```

That swaps fields of a to fields of b and vice-versa.

I tried to create such function but It's been rather lengthy and inefficient since the values don't get changed as expected.
Any easy ways to do this ?

Comment: Are those 2 objects of same class? Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Share what types `a` and `b` are and your own attempt please!

Comment: Yes these are same object type TreeNode

Comment: Let me guess that you are implementing a tree, `a` and `b` are child nodes of the same parent. Right? Then just swap the `leftNode` and  `rightNode` references of the parent node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the types of the fields are:

- value is String
- index is int
- parent is TreeNode
- leftChild is TreeNode
- rightChild is TreeNode

So use the classic method of swapping values for each of the fileds:

```
public static void swap(TreeNode a, TreeNode b) {
    String tempValue = a.value;
    a.value = b.value;
    b.value = tempValue;

    int tempIndex = a.index;
    a.index = b.index;
    b.index = tempIndex;

    TreeNode tempNode = a.parent;
    a.parent = b.parent;
    b.parent = tempNode; 

    tempNode = a.leftChild;
    a.leftChild = b.leftChild;
    b.leftChild = tempNode;    

    tempNode = a.rightChild;
    a.rightChild = b.rightChild;
    b.rightChild = tempNode;    
}
```

Comment: This might bring the OP into real trouble, e.g. if the instances are used as keys in a HashMap.

Comment: It's the OP's desire for the objects to swap field values. He can maintain any side effects.

Comment: While technically correct, it won't solve the OP's real problem because it will leave the tree in a corrupted state. Next question will be about debugging. ;-) I will give you +1 nevertheless because it's a 100% correct answer to OP's question. It's the question that's wrong.

Comment: Why do you think *it will leave the tree in a corrupted state*? The node a will swap places with nod b, because of swapping all 3 positioning properties: parent, leftchild and rightchild.

Comment: After that, it's the OP's responsibillity to change the children's parents etc.

Answer (score 0):

Copy values from `b` to temporary variables, set values from `a` to `b`, copy values from temporary variables to `a`. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can't really do that (at least if you mean your question literally).

What's your situation? Something similar to:

```
    // This is the aTreeNode instance.
    TreeNode a = new TreeNode("ValueA", 4711, parentA, leftChildA, rightChildA);

    // This is the aTreeNode instance.
    TreeNode b = new TreeNode("ValueB", 4712, parentB, leftChildB, rightChildB);
```

You have two variables `a` and `b`, referencing each a `TreeNode` instance (which I called `aTreeNode` and `bTreeNode`, just to give them names I can talk about). And these instances have different values in their fields. Let's depict it:

```
    a -> aTreeNode instance
         ------------------
         "ValueA"
         4711
         -> parentA instance
         -> leftChildA instance
         -> rightChildA instance

    b -> bTreeNode instance
         ------------------
         "ValueB"
         4712
         -> parentB instance
         -> leftChildB instance
         -> rightChildB instance
```

If you call a method like `swap(a, b)`, the method gets the references to the `aTreeNode` and the `bTreeNode` instances. As the method doesn't know where these references came from (in our case, the variables `a` and `b`, but it might as well be an array element or the result of some other method call), the best thing it can do is to swap the contents inside these instances:

```
    a -> aTreeNode instance
         ------------------
         "ValueB"
         4712
         -> parentB instance
         -> leftChildB instance
         -> rightChildB instance

    b -> bTreeNode instance
         ------------------
         "ValueA"
         4711
         -> parentA instance
         -> leftChildA instance
         -> rightChildA instance
```

So, after the `swap(a, b)` call, `a` still references the `aTreeNode` instance, and `b` the `bTreeNode`, they only swapped their contents. And such radical changes of the contents of an instance don't fit well into the Java philosophy, bringing you into trouble with many library classes, e.g. all kinds of collections and maps.

So, you'd better swap the two variables without a method call:

```
    TreeNode a = new TreeNode("ValueA", 4711, parentA, leftChildA, rightChildA);
    TreeNode b = new TreeNode("ValueB", 4712, parentB, leftChildB, rightChildB);

    TreeNode temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
```

It's much faster, cleaner, and the result is:

```
    a -> bTreeNode instance
         ------------------
         "ValueB"
         4712
         -> parentB instance
         -> leftChildB instance
         -> rightChildB instance

    b -> aTreeNode instance
         ------------------
         "ValueA"
         4711
         -> parentA instance
         -> leftChildA instance
         -> rightChildA instance
```